# Unable to activate Photoshop CS4 on a new computer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs4, deactivation, software-activation

I've sold my old Apple Mac Pro 3,1 to get a new Mac Pro 4,1 and moved my Areca RAID card  with all drives and graphics card to it.

Now my Photoshop CS4 is displaying message:

"Our records indicate that this serial numbe has already been used to set up and activate Photoshop CS4 on two other machines, which is maximum allowed.".

How to deactivate my old copies ? I've only activated it once and even in case of disk failure I've always restored all data from disk image.

Is this activation related to the processor or MAC address ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not certain how Adobe manages the security and they don't seem happy to tell.  I encountered this once and it required a call to Adobe to explain that the software was being installed after a failure and there was no system backup. They accepted this and I was able to activate.  The call took at least 40 minutes before I spoke to someone.

Comment: Windows and Office deactivated too, but I was able to activate them via automated phone service in just 5 minutes (I use BOX'ed editions only).

Comment: Yea, you're gonna have to call Adobe

Comment: Just two minutes via live chat with Adobe and all is working again !